# Minimizing the negative log likelihood: Error in optim() caused by the initial values

Tags: r, optimization, mle

I want to obtain the maximum likelihood parameters (MLE) for a cumulative normal curve fitted to some proportion data by direct minimization of the negative log likelihood (without using glm). For some initial values introduced to optim() there is not problem:

```
x <- c(-0.250, -0.056,  0.137,  0.331,  0.525,  0.719,  0.912,  1.100,  1.300)
k <- c(0, 0, 5, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)
n <- c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)


nll <- function(p) {
  phi <- pnorm(x, p[1], p[2])
  -sum(k * log(phi) + (n - k) * log(1 - phi))
}

para<- optim(c(0.5, 0.1), nll)$par

xseq <- seq(-.5, 1.5, len = 100)
yseq <- pnorm(xseq, para[1],para[2])
curve <- data.frame(xseq, yseq)

dat <- data.frame(x, k, n)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat,aes(x = x, y = k / n)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(data = curve, aes(x = xseq, y = yseq))
```

But, if I use initial values that are actually closer to the MLE parameters

```
 para<- optim(c(0.1, 0.1), nll)$par
```

I obtained the following error:

```
Error in optim(c(0.1, 0.1), nll) : function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
```

It seems that the error is caused by some infinities in the evaluation of the negative log likelihood. I found that if I increase the precision using the `log.p` option of pnorm, I don't obtatin the error

```
nll <- function(p) {
  logphi1 <- pnorm(x, p[1], p[2], lower.tail = T, log.p = T)
  logphi2 <- pnorm(x, p[1], p[2], lower.tail = F, log.p = T)
  -sum(k * logphi1 + (n - k) * logphi2)
}
para<- optim(c(0.1, 0.1), nll)$par
```

but the problem is that in addition to `pnorm` I also want to fit curves that are `a + b * pnorm` with `a` and `b` constants and in those cases I cannot used `log.p` to increase the precision.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that replacing the very small numbers by the machine epsilon and the numbers very close to 1 by 1 - (machine epsilon), the error does not occur and the fit seems sensible.

```
x <- c(-0.250, -0.056,  0.137,  0.331,  0.525,  0.719,  0.912,  1.100,  1.300)
k <- c(0, 0, 5, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)
n <- c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)

nll <- function(p) {
  phi <- pnorm(x, p[1], p[2])
  phi[phi < .Machine$double.eps] <- .Machine$double.eps
  phi[phi > (1 - .Machine$double.eps)] <- 1 - .Machine$double.eps
  -sum(k * log(phi) + (n - k) * log(1 - phi))
}

para<- optim(c(0.1, 0.1), nll)$par

xseq <- seq(-.5, 1.5, len = 100)
yseq <- pnorm(xseq, para[1],para[2])
curve <- data.frame(xseq, yseq)

dat <- data.frame(x, k, n)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat,aes(x = x, y = k / n)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(data = curve, aes(x = xseq, y = yseq))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the 8th datapoint & parameter values; they cause a NaN in the evaluation of the likelihood, because `pnorm` evaluates to 1 (numerically):

```
p <- c(0.1,0.1)
pnorm(x[8], p[1], p[2])
## 1
1-pnorm(x[8], p[1], p[2])
## 0
pnorm(x[8], p[1], p[2], lower.tail=FALSE)
## 7.6e-24
```

The latter value lies below the machine-epsilon, so even if you write `1 - pnorm(x[8], p[1], p[2], lower.tail=FALSE)` in your likelihood, this won't avoid the underflow.